# Can I get the real full executed command of Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec?

Tags: java, linux, ansible

When I tried to run **Ansible** with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` with Java

Here is what I did:

```
String[] cmd = {"ansible-playbook", "/path/to/playbook", "--extra-vars", "'{\"filePath\":\"/path/to/file\"}'"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null);
```

I got error message like this:

```
FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'filePath' is undefined"}
```

However when I executed the same command with terminal:

```
ansible-playbook /path/to/playbook --extra-vars '{"filePath":"/path/to/file"}'
```

Everything was fine...

I think there must be some differences between the command I ran in terminal and Java, maybe apostrophe or quotation mark ?

I'm wondering is there any way to get the real executed command of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`?  Just like I can get command line history of some user by `history`...

Comment: You don't need the single quotes in the third parameter: the exec command "quotes" it for you. `"{\"filePath\":\"/path/to/file\"}"` is fine.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks!  Why single quotes version works on terminal...

Comment: Because the terminal doesn't quote it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding additional quotes in your third parameter:

```
"'{\"filePath\":\"/path/to/file\"}'"
```

If you do this, you're not executing the same command in your shell as you have above. You're actually executing (in bash):

```
ansible-playbook /path/to/playbook --extra-vars ''\''{"filePath":"/path/to/file"}'\'''
```

You don't need the single quotes around the value here: because you're passing these values directly, you don't have to worry about the quoting that you'd have to do in a shell. You can simply use:

```
"{\"filePath\":\"/path/to/file\"}"
```